# How to declare an angular-bootstrap modal in a way that is safe for minimization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have implemented an angular modal dialog box following the guidelines given at: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. The code below works fine when the non-minified files are accessed, but it fails when minification is applied. I have narrowed the problem down to the declaration of the modalInstanceCtrl function below, however I am not clear on how I can implement this function in a minification-friendly manner. I have tried to declare the modalInstanceCtrl function using standard controller syntax, but in that case, the function is not found by the $modal.open call.

The error message that I receive from the minified code is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

What is the best way to declare this controller so  that it can be both minified as well as called from the $modal.open function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
lxModalSupportServices.factory('lxModalSupportService', 
    function ($modal, $log, $timeout) {

    var modalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $log, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
    };

    return {
        showCameraAndMicrophoneModalWindow : function(scope, htmlTemplate) {
            var ModalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: htmlTemplate,
                controller: modalInstanceCtrl
            });

    ....
    }
});
```

Comment: Register the controller with your application and tell it the name and parameter names/order. e.g. MainApp.controller("MyExample.Controls.Menu", ["$element", "$scope", MyExampleControls.Menu]);. there are more options, Check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried adding the following declaration to the code but it still fails when minified: lxModalSupportServices.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$modalInstance', ModalInstanceCtrl]);

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with the fact that my build system (grunt) is minimizing and combining ui-bootstrap-tpls.js with a bunch of other angular javascript files. Perhaps there is something there that has not been minimized correctly, and that only gets exposed during the modal controller execution. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: The problem is; Your controller takes 3 parameters (named), when minified, there parameter names are also modified and angular cannot do dependency injection anymore. You must tell angular an order of parameters (normally done with registering the controller like mentioned before). There are multiple ways of correcting that. Check the injector link.

Comment: Additionally to specifying `lxModalSupportServices.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$modalInstance', ModalInstanceCtrl]);`, you also need to change `$modal.open({...controller: ModalInstanceCtrl` to `...controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'` (notice the quotes around `ModalInstanceCtrl`).

Comment: Thanks, that last point is what I was missing, as described in the answer that I have selected below.

Comment: Hi marvin, my grunt build system runs ngmin, which normally takes care of converting the stanadard function definitions into minification-safe function declarations. It is quite useful and normally works great, but I think that I had written this controller in a non-standard way which was confusing the ngmin script.

Comment: @AlexanderMarquardt: BTW, **[ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin)** has been deprecated in favor of **[ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)**, so you might want to use that instead.

Comment: @ExpertSystem thanks for the information. I didn't know about the ngmin depreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the declaration to

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = [
  '$scope', '$log', '$modalInstance',
  function($scope, $log, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.ok = function () {
      $modalInstance.close();
    };
  }
];
```

and try again. If it still fails, probably the problem is somewhere else.

Normally I would declare the controller for `$modal` separately:

```
lxModalSupportServices.controller('AddCommentModalCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  'use strict';

  // Implementation...
});
```

Then use it with string

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: htmlTemplate,
  controller: 'AddCommentModalCtrl',
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer which has solved my problem! It turns out that adding the controller name in quotes is crucial (and  was still missing from my implementation) in addition to declaring the controller using the standard controller 'quoted' declaration syntax (the last two bits of code that you wrote).

Comment: @AlexanderMarquardt It's usually better to declare controller with `.controller()` and use it with `string`. It makes your code more modular and testable. As you mentioned `ngmin`, as far as I know, `ngmin` does not support annotating internal injectables (like your case).